# Learning to use perl like regular expressions in PIG Latin.

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, latin

Is there a way to extract certain words from a file in Pig Latin, eg: I want all words in a large file with tweets, that have a # in the beginning.

```
Input :  What a lovely day! #Sunshine
Output : Sunshine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at REGEX_EXTRACT: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/func.html#regex-extract

This should work (extracts the last word with a # in front of it from your_field):

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(your_field, '.*#(\\w+)($|\\s.*)', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, using FILTER worked for me: startswithHash = filter <> by <> matches '#.*' ;